# PHP cURL "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to"

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssl, curl, ubuntu-14.04

When I try to run my script using cURL on my computer via XAMPP, everything works perfectly:

[image]

When I move it onto my server (Ubuntu 14.04 x64), it stops working and I continue to get this type of error:

[image]

I am so lost as to how to fix this. I've tried to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);` but it doesn't work.

Comment: quick fix, if im right `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: This is probably not a fix with "unknown protocol". Additionally it is a very bad idea to consider disabling verification a __fix__. It is at most a temporary workaround and there need to be a clear warning that using this workaround affects seriously the security.

Answer (score 0):

"Unknown protocol" error usually means, that the client and server don't agree to the SSL protocol version. For example might set the protocol to SSL 3.0 like you did with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3)`, but the server might have disable SSL 3.0 like most servers do today because this protocol is considered insecure.

If these information are not enough please post the relevant client code and the server setup. Also, check with other clients (like browser) to make sure that only your curl-client is affected and thus the main problem is not at the server side.

Apart from that, don't cross-post your problem to multiple sites.